Whole PDF in Italics and Boldface when I use Fakebold and Fakeslant
I am using an imported font (Ballard Basic) and LuaLateX to generate the PDF file. However, all the text in the PDF is in italic and boldface (this is not what I want). Help! Here is the code I am using:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\setmainfont[
    Path = ./, 
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldFont = *,
    ItalicFont = *,
    BoldItalicFont = *,
    FakeBold = 2.5,
    FakeSlant = 0.2
]{BallardBasic}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you get errors or warnings? Can you show the log file?

BoldFeatures ={FakeBold=2}  to just apply Fake Bold to bold fonts

You're applying FakeBold and FakeSlant generally and not just to the bold and italic fonts.
\setmainfont{BallardBasic}[
    Path = ./, 
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldFont = *,
    ItalicFont = *,
    BoldItalicFont = *,
    BoldFeatures={FakeBold = 2.5},
    ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant = 0.2},
    BoldItalicFeatures={FakeBold = 2.5,FakeSlant = 0.2},
]

Here's an example (with a different font that only comes in the upright variant)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{FedorovskUnicode}[
%    Path = ./, 
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldFont = *,
    ItalicFont = *,
    BoldItalicFont = *,
    BoldFeatures={FakeBold = 2.5},
    ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant = 0.2},
    BoldItalicFeatures={FakeBold = 2.5,FakeSlant = 0.2},
]

\begin{document}

abcdef \textit{abcdef} \textbf{abcdef} \textit{\textbf{abcdef}}

\end{document}


